# iOS auto layout support for all iphones?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout

I'm using autolayout storyboards for my ios app which is only for iPhone. When I submit, Apple reject it saying that the app should support iPhone 3.5 inch for ipad view on iphone resolution but making the UI for iPhone 3.5 inch is bit hard.

If I change it to support iPhone 3.5 inch onwards it gives bad view for iphone 5 inch. The contents are not centric there's long space for iphone 5 inch. What are the solutions?
Can I configure the settings to support iPhone 4 onwards?
or else Can I make two storyboards for iPhone 3.5 inch & 5 inches?

Comment: Since the iPhone 3.5 inch view is only used for iPad, an alternative would be to make your app Universal and then take advantage of the larger layout space that the iPad provides.

Comment: I think your real issue is that you don't know how to configure the auto layout constraints to get your desired look.  You should post your auto layout constraints and screen captures of the views on both devices and ask for help on how to configure your constraints to get the desired look.

Comment: _"making the ui for iphone 3.5 inch is bit hard"_, well, Apple does not care about a developer's problem, they care about their customers only, if they say that you must do something to get your app approved – you must do it. and the auto-layout is a powerful tool to support multiple screen sizes, albeit not perfect for all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make 2 storyboards and switch them, depending on screen height, but why you can't adjust constraints for all iPhones screens? Usually this is possible.

One way for complex layouts - create constraint outlets and change them in code.

Another way - divide design to smaller `UIViews`, that contains elements, like container and set constraints between them.